# How to remove all tags from html string?

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsattributedstring, foundation

I need to get string without html tags.
This is the part of this raw text

```
.</p>\n\n<p>For a long time, scientists have been opposed to the id
```

I use

```
     let htmlData = NSString(string: text).data(using: String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue)
                let options = [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:
                        NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
                let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: htmlData ?? Data(),
                                                                          options: options,
                                                                          documentAttributes: nil)
   print(attributedString.string)
```

The issue, that parser delete one \n. I have to get "\n\n For a long ...."

But the result is "\nFor a long time, scientists have been opposed to the idea of describing animals using hu..."
This /n is very important.

How to remove all tags from  html string ?

Comment: You still have one line break instead of two. Why not just do another pass and replace all occurrences of `\n` with `\n\n`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
extension String{
var htmlConvertedString : String{
    let string = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
    return string
}}
```

try this

and call like this `let val  = str.htmlConvertedString`

`print(val)`

Comment: Why are you removing full stops?

Answer (score 0):

***ViewController.swift***

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

var content = ".</p>\n\n<p>For a long time, scientists have been opposed to the id"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let attr = try? NSAttributedString(htmlString: content, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17))
    label.attributedText = attr
    
}
```

***html extension***

```
extension NSAttributedString {

    convenience init(htmlString html: String, font: UIFont? = nil, useDocumentFontSize: Bool = true) throws {
        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any] = [
            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]
        
        let data = html.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        guard (data != nil), let fontFamily = font?.familyName, let attr = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil) else {
          
            try self.init(data: data ?? Data(html.utf8), options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
            return
        }
        
        let fontSize: CGFloat? = useDocumentFontSize ? nil : font!.pointSize
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attr.length)
        
        attr.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: range, options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) { attrib, range, _ in
            if let htmlFont = attrib as? UIFont {
                let traits = htmlFont.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
                var descrip = htmlFont.fontDescriptor.withFamily(fontFamily)
                
                if (traits.rawValue & UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits.traitBold.rawValue) != 0 {
                    descrip = descrip.withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold)!
                }
                
                if (traits.rawValue & UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits.traitItalic.rawValue) != 0 {
                    descrip = descrip.withSymbolicTraits(.traitItalic)!
                }
            
                attr.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.black, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attr.length))
                attr.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont(descriptor: descrip, size: fontSize ?? htmlFont.pointSize), range: range)
            }
        }
        self.init(attributedString: attr)
    }
}
```